# How to mount to subdirectory of autofs

Tags: linux, mount, directory-structure, automounting, autofs

I have follong problem - I'd like to use autfs in one place to mount to subdirectory of autofs. I.e. I'd like to have something like:

```
foo -fs=...
bar/baz -fs=...
```

The problem is that (according to logs) autofs tries to find `bar` when I try to list files by `ls /mnt/bar/baz`. Is it possible to 'fake' hierarchy in autofs?